# how to check if file something(a number).php exists?

Tags: php, file, file-exists

Say I have all these files in a folder:

```
something(34324).php
something(34).php
something(3433454546).php
something(65565).php
something(9887).php
something(4585).php // ect ect
```

Now I need to somehow check if any `something.php` file exists (ignoring the number).

so if `something(a_number).php` exists in the folder, return true...

Any ideas on how I'd do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob), which returns an array of directory contents matching a wildcard pattern.

```
$somethings = glob('something*.php');
if (!empty($somethings)) {
    // something exists
}
```